# Extend session lifetime in Symfony2

Tags: ajax, session, symfony

I am trying to extend sesion_liftime before Symfony2 sesion will be destroyed.

I am showing the user that he will be log out in few seconds, and when he/she confirm to extend the sesion I send an ajax request to controller which should extend the sesion. But the problem is that the request is not working.

I try few diferent solutions but none of them worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             var timeoutID;

            function delayedAlert() {
              timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 15000);
            }

            function slowAlert() {
                setTimeout(logout, 5500)
              var r=confirm("You will be logout in 5 seconds!");
              if (r==true)
              {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/interactivo/web/app_dev.php/check',
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                     }
                });
                alert("You wont be logout");
              }
            }

            function logout() {alert("You are logout");};

            delayedAlert();
        </script>


/**
* @Route("/check")
*/
public function indexAction()
{
//        FIRST ATTEMPT
//        $value = 'something from somewhere';
//

//        setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
//        setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
//        setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);

//        SECOND ATTEMPT
//        header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//        echo 'TEST';

//        THIRD ATTEMPT
        $session = $this->container->get('session');

        $lastUsed = new \DateTime();
        $lastUsed->setTimestamp($session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed());

        return $this->render('GLHomeBundle:Default:sesion.html.twig', array( 'entities'=> $lastUsed));
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not a good solution (if it works), but the session's cookie in symfony is called "PHPSESSID". Try to set the life time of this cookie to the time needed ? I use this method to pass my session accross Drupal and Varnish to the client, so I think that it could work to extend life time of the session.

Regards,
Peekmo

Comment: The problem is that this ajax request is not calling the controller, I have already found that if i will just use session it will automatically change the property od lastModified so iw will be enought to extend the session. But how I can call this indexAction?

Comment: url: '/check',  that's sure that you can call your controller by using the route in the url, if it doesn't work, your problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found the solution for this. I used SessionKeepAliveListener from this [site](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=36827&p=125930). 
I am calling the controller via AJAX like this:

```
function slowAlert() {
            setTimeout(logout, 40000)
          var r=confirm("You will be logout in 20s!");
          if (r==true)
          {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('_demo_hello') }}",
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                 }
            });
            alert("You wont be logout");
          }
        }
```

The controller is very easy :D

```
/**
 * @Route("/check", name="_demo_hello")
 */
public function checkAction()
{      
    $response = new Response();

    return $response;
}
```